# How to get the actual file after being uploaded in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-upload

Here is how I am uploading the file via my view derived from HomeController@index:

```
<form action='csvUpload' method='POST'>
    @csrf
    <input type='file' name='dataframe' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button type='submit' name='upload'>Predict</button>
</form>
```

Here is my web routes:

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/csvUpload', 'HomeController@predict')->name('home');
```

Here is my HomeController@predict:

```
public function predict(Request $request)
{   
    $file = $request->dataframe;
    var_dump($file); # I want this to be the actual file or
                     # To store it locally and then get that file path
}
```

Which is returning `string(13) "languages.csv"` when I upload my CSV file. How can I get the actual file? I have tried `$request->file('dataframe')` but that returns null.

Comment: Why are you adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your input? It should be on your form right?

Comment: I asked a previous question because the file wasn't being sent over, and got told I needed to add it. Turns out I wasn't POST ing the file, I was sending it as a GET request which was the issue @Mozammil

Comment: It's meant to be added on your [<form>](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) element. Not the input.

Comment: Also safer to use blade functions to generate form https://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/processing-file-uploads-with-laravel-5/

Comment: I tried to use `File::*` but I was getting errors about the method being incorrect. Every tutorial I looked wanted me to reference the DB etc which I don't need, how could I use this? @lchachurski

Comment: I think the `File` class is for something else. At the tutorial above, they are using `Form::file('image', null)` this has to go within `Form::open`. It will generate correct html for you, the adventage is that you don't need to bother with `enctype` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encoding type should be on your form like this:

```
<form action='csvUpload' method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</form>
```

And then in your controller you can access the file like this:

```
$request->file('dataframe')
```

Comment: right, I really am monging it today! Thank you for this answer, that has worked perfectly. Ill mark it when I can

Answer (score 0):

`enctype="multipart/form-data"` should be on the `<form>`
And use `$request->file(name-input)`